# ASP.NET5 MVC 6 CORS vue.js request not allowed

Tags: javascript, c#, cors, asp.net-core-mvc, vue.js

I'm stuck on something. I test my api from chome postman app with requests like:

```
http://localhost:50000/api/user/user_name/machines
```

and it works.
I started building front end in vue.js and try the following:

```
getReports() {
    this.$http
      .get('http://localhost:50000/api/user/user_name/machines', (data) => {
        this.data = data;
      })
      .error((err) => console.log(err))
  }
```

and of course i get

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:50000/api/user/user_name/machines. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

I previously try some react.js and came across same problem so like then i just added

```
services.AddCors();
```

and

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
```

to my startup.cs file but no luck this time. I remember it worked on react.js. I can also get data directly from the browser - just by going to this url. Why vue.js has problems?

my startup.cs file:
http://pastebin.pl/view/b93c9e2c

Comment: it works when I delete:
Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token');
but why header is thee problem?
A also add builder.AllowAnyHeader(); but it didn't help

Comment: Where is the line you deleted? I'm going crazy with the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a [Cross Origin Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (cors) limitations.  This usually happens when you are using fully qualified url when making a server request that is a different origin than the hosting document.

In your example you are using http://localhost:50000/api/user/user_name/machines in your request. If possible you can use a relative path like /api/user/user_name/machines instead so the request will be made based on the url entered in the browser.  This will make sure the browser doesn't send a preflight request.